# How do I keep the browser open on a failed test using Selenium+Nightwatch+Chromedriver?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, nightwatch.js

I'm using Nightwatch, Selenium, and Chrome Driver to conduct automated UI testing.  Sometimes there are test failures on any number of remote environments.  To debug the failures locally, I would like to keep the browser open on test failure.

I used to be able to do this using config settings in nightwatch.json and nightwatch.conf.js, but I lost my config settings cheat-sheet in a hard drive failure, and despite my best efforts on google I can't seem to find the right combination again.

If I remember correctly, it wasn't any kind of `keepBrowserOpen: true` type flag.  If memory serves, it was some type of timeout set to a silly high number combined with something else like detachDriver.  I've checked the Selenium documentation with specific focus on the [Chrome Driver Options](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/chrome_exports_Options.html), and the list of [Chrome Driver options](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/), but I haven't found any working combinations.

What am I missing?

Here is my nightwatch.json

```
{
    "output_folder": "tests/automation/reports",
    "end_session_on_fail": false,
    "test_settings": {
        "default": {
            "selenium_port": 4444,
            "screenshots": {
                "enabled": true,
                "path": "tests/automation/reports/screenshots"
            },
            "javascriptEnabled": true,
            "acceptSslCerts": true,
            "acceptInsecureCerts": true,
            "globals": {
                "waitForConditionTimeout": 10000
            }
        },
        "chrome": {
            "extends": "default",
            "desiredCapabilities": {
                "browserName": "chrome",
                "javascriptEnabled": true,
                "acceptSslCerts": true,
                "acceptInsecureCerts": true,
                "chromeOptions": {
                    "args": [
                        "--no-sandbox",
                        "--disable-gpu"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And my nightwatch.conf.js

```
const geckoDriver = require('geckodriver');
const chromeDriver = require('chromedriver');
const seleniumServer = require('selenium-server');

module.exports = (function (settings) {
    settings.selenium = {
        start_process: true,
        server_path: seleniumServer.path,
        log_path: 'tests/automation/reports/',
        host: 'localhost',
        port: 4444,
        cli_args: {
            'webdriver.chrome.driver': chromeDriver.path,
            'webdriver.gecko.driver': geckoDriver.path,
            'webdriver.edge.driver': 'C:\\windows\\system32\\MicrosoftWebDriver.exe',
            'webdriver.port': '4444'
        }
    };

    return settings;
})(require('./nightwatch.json'));
```

Selenium Version is 2.35.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not an elegant solution but close to what you are looking for. Basically, we can check the value of `browser.currentTest.results.errors` in `afterEach()` and in case if the value is more than 0, then we can just pause the test there, keeping the browser session alive.

```
afterEach: function(browser) {
    if(browser.currentTest.results.errors > 0) {
        browser.pause()
    }
```

Comment: Its not an elegant problem.  Its really helpful to a human to have the browser session open for debugging locally, but that's never desired when running under the automation suite. I had been capturing screenshots in a similar `if` block. Then calling `browser.end()` to close the browser. If I comment that out I can view the test state in the headed browser. Thanks!